# How can I make this quiz with adding system work using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this quiz every div is a question. I need it to be absolute so every time the next button is clicked the next div shows and the previous hides and the opposite happens when the previous buttons are clicked.

Here is what I need help with:

1. I stored the answers into an array and compare the `val()` entered in the field to the corresponding array (`answers`), then added into an adding system (`totalcorrect++`). I need the total scored to be shown in the `#result` div. I don't know how to to that.
2. I can see that I'm getting the calculating right but the problem I'm having is that every time I press preview and then press next question again, the sum for that question (or as many questions I go back to) is done again, so it doubles the `totalcorrect` value. How do I prevent that from happening?
3. Is there a better way of writing my arrays so it is categorised by questions and it's answered?

```js
var answers = [
  ["A"],
  ["red"],
  ["green"],
  ["Concord"],
  ["Pinot Noir"],
  ["Lemberger"]

];

var totalCorrect = 0;
var totalAnswer = answers.length;

//Page 1
$("#btnNext_q1").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $('.checbox-q').css({
    "opacity": 0,
    "z-index": 1
  });
  
  $('.fillBlanks-q').css({
    "opacity": 1,
    "z-index": 20
  });

  if ($("#q1-a1").val() == answers[0]) {
    totalCorrect++;
  }
});


//Page 2
$("#btnPrev_q2").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $('.checbox-q').css({
    "opacity": 1,
    "z-index": 20
  });
  
  $('.fillBlanks-q').css({
    "opacity": 0,
    "z-index": 1
  });
});

$("#btnNext_q2").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $('.fillBlanks-q').css({
    "opacity": 0,
    "z-index": 1
  });
  
  $('.list-q').css({
    "opacity": 1,
    "z-index": 20
  });

  if ($("#q2-a1").val() == answers[1]) {
    totalCorrect++;
  }
  if ($("#q2-a2").val() == answers[2]) {
    totalCorrect++;
  }
});


//Page 3
$("#btnPrev_q3").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $('.fillBlanks-q').css({
    "opacity": 1,
    "z-index": 20
  });
  
  $('.list-q').css({
    "opacity": 0,
    "z-index": 1
  });
});

$("#submit").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $('list-q').css({
    "opacity": 0,
    "z-index": 1
  });
  
  $('#result').css({
    "opacity": 1,
    "z-index": 20
  });

  if ($("#q3-a1").val() == answers[3]) {
    totalCorrect++;
  }
  
  if ($("#q3-a2").val() == answers[4]) {
    totalCorrect++;
  }
  
  if ($("#q3-a1").val() == answers[5]) {
    totalCorrect++;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checbox-q" style="opacity: 0; position:absolute; z-index:18;">
  <span>What is an animal?<?span>
  <input type="checkbox" id="q1-a1" value="A">
  <label>Dog</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="q1-a2" value="B">
  <label>Tiger</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="q1-a3" value="C">
  <label>Flower</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="q1-a4" value="4">
  <label>Cat</label>
  <button id="btnPrev_q1">Preview</button>
  <button id="btnNext_q1">Next</button>
</div>

<div class="fillBlanks-q" style="opacity: 0; position:absolute; z-index:17;">
  <span>Apples can be in the colour 
    <input type="text" id="q2-a1"> 
    and 
    <input type="text" id="q2-a2">
  </span>
  <button id="btnPrev_q2">Preview</button>
  <button id="btnNext_q2">Next</button>
</div>

<div class="list-q" style="opacity: 0; position:absolute; z-index:16;">
  <span>List 3 types of Grapes<?span>
  <ol>
    <li><input type="text" id="q3-a1"></li>
    <li><input type="text" id="q3-a2"></li>
    <li><input type="text" id="q3-a3"></li>
  </ol>
  <button id="btnPrev_q3">Preview</button>
  <button id="submit">Next</button>
</div>
<div id="result" class="pages" style="opacity: 0; position:absolute; z-index:11;"><div>
```

Comment: I was just in a rush on the last one and decided to write another one when had more time.
I really need help with this. If you have any question let me know and I will answer it.

Comment: When I run your snippet I see nothing whatsoever.

Comment: hi Jamiec. thanks for replying. I need the result to show in the div="result" but don't know how to do that.

Comment: I very new to JavaScript(Jquery) and it can be very daunting at the beginning so would appreciate some help to make this work.

Comment: you should add an answered status to avoid wrong increment during navigation, for examples adding a custom data attribute and then tests if it is present before increments the counter. $("#result").text(totalCorrect) should do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I know this should be a comment but I don't have enough rep to make comments yet.

Your HTML is a bit out, you've been a bit trigger happy with the shift key in a few places  (<?span> on lines 3 & 27 instead of `</span>`)

You haven't closed the last div tag

The opacity is set to 0 on everything, that's why nothing is displaying when people click run code snippet  Remove the opacity from the style tags or set it to 100 so people can see the form.

To put the total score in the result div:

```
$('#result').text(totalCorrect);
```

Once we can see your code running, I'll edit this to answer the other part of your question.